# Dealing with spaces in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm a RegEx newbie and this has been driving me nuts for the past 48 hours. I tried everything I could while reading hundreds of examples and documents. I want to learn.

I need to extract the month name from strings like these, with the month being the word in the middle (multilingual):

```
10 july  2014
9 dicembre2014
1januar2011
18août2002 (note: non-[A-z] character in the month if it matters)
```

The closest I got was `[\D]{3,}(?=.{4,})` yielding:

```
' july '
' dicembre'
'januar'
'août'
```

But it still matches the spaces around the name. I tried adding `[^\s]` but obviously it's not that simple.

What is the simplest RegEx way to find the right match?

Comment: You can only somewhat reliably extract the dates if the follow the format as shown above (day, month name, 4-digit year). If the presentation can be arbitrary, it will be ambiguous to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `re.UNICODE` flag, you can use unicode properties, and thus a `\w` also matches all letters from all scripts (including `û`, `ñ`, `á`, etc.). Then, `[^\W\d_]` would match only letters, but from any script:

- `\w` matches word characters (letters, digits or underscore "`_`")
- `\W` is the negated shorthand, it matches non-word characters (same as `[^\w]`)
- `\d` matches digits
- So `[^\W\d_]` will match anything EXCEPT non-word characters, digits or "`_`"... which means it will only match letters

#### Code:

```python
#python 3.4.3
import re

str = u"10 july  2014 \n 9 dicembre2014 \n 1januar2011\n 18août2002"
pattern = r'([0-3]?\d)\s*([^\W\d_]{3,})\s*((?:\d{2}){1,2})'
result = re.findall(pattern, str, re.UNICODE)

for date in result :
    print(date)
```

#### Output:

```
('10', 'july', '2014')
('9', 'dicembre', '2014')
('1', 'januar', '2011')
('18', 'août', '2002')
```

Check online [here](http://rextester.com/UTBVM53332)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I can't find info on the underscore you have in the exclusions. What is it for? I don't see any difference when testing without it.

Comment: @chris: it excludes literal underscores ("`_`") from matching. Test with "`10m_ay15`" to see the difference. I added the info to the answer